# Styling an image inside a label

Tags: html, css

The inline styling works perfectly.

However, I cannot seem to make it work when added to my stylesheet. I am a novice when it comes to CSS and struggle with targeting nested elements. These don't work:

```css
    .icon img {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 40px;
    }

    label .icon img {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 40px;
    }
```

```html
<label for="btn" class="icon"><img style="margin-top: 20px; width: 40px;" src="images/hamburger3.png"></label>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: omit the space between `label` and `.icon`.

Comment: With the space between label and .icon omitted, both should work - unless there are other places from where this CSS gets overridden. Are you sure that your CSS is being loaded, and that there is no other CSS?

Comment: I should have stated that the label is inside a nav element if that makes any difference. Still not working; I will have to construct a test page with minimal CSS in case it is being overridden somewhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is perfect. Remove the inline styling and add this

```css
.icon img {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for="btn" class="icon">
      <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"></label>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to specify the styles inside the image tag, specificity from the tag via img, check more about specificity, check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* the selector could also be ".icon img" */
    label img {
        margin-top: 20px;
        width: 40px;
    }
</style>

<label for="btn" class="icon">
    <img src="images/hamburger3.png">
</label>
```